# mongodb C driver authentication

Tags: c, authentication, mongodb

I can't seem to find documentation on authentication into mongodb from the C driver.  The C driver API has no information on it as far as I can tell.  However, [this link](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CDRIVER-65) makes me think that it's possible.  A link or a code snippet would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the function to call.

```
MONGO_EXPORT int mongo_cmd_authenticate     (
        mongo *         conn,
        const char *    db,
        const char *    user,
        const char *    pass
    )

Authenticate a user.

Parameters:
        conn    a mongo object.
        db      the database to authenticate against.
        user    the user name to authenticate.
        pass    the user's password.

Returns:
    MONGO_OK on sucess and MONGO_ERROR on failure.
```

Here's an excerpt from the test code as an example - mongo-c-driver/test/auth_test.c

```
if ( mongo_connect( conn , TEST_SERVER, 27017 ) ) {
    printf( "failed to connect\n" );
    exit( 1 );
}

ASSERT( mongo_cmd_authenticate( conn, db, "user", "password" ) == MONGO_OK );

...
```

Hope that this helps.  Here are some links for futher information.

References:

MongoDB C Language Center - http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/C+Language+Center

MongoDB C Driver Documentation - http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/

MongoDB C Driver API Docs - http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/api/index.html

mongo.h File Referenc - http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/api/mongo_8h.html

mongo_cmd_authenticate - http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/api/mongo_8h.html#a715aaa6b82e23486e6caad2b544f2ebf

MongoDB C Driver source code - https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver

test/auth_test.c - https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/blob/master/test/auth_test.c